# How do you search for nouns that contain the sequence of letters sb in the Corpus of Contemporary American English?

Tags: corpora

I am trying to design a word list for a phonetics project. I can use wildcard searches in the corpus such as * sb *  which will return all words that contain this sequence of letters (either medially or word-initially). However, I want to restrict this search to a specific lexical category (nouns). Is there a way to search for this.

Short version: How do I ask the corpus for all nouns that contain the sequence of letters sb?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly straightforward and should be captured by the help pages on the COCA site:

> *sb*.[n*]

I created [a presentation that explains the basics of COCA searching](http://www.slideshare.net/bohemicus/online-corpus-literacy-teacher-for-literacy-teachers) (slides 26 - 45). There's also [a video on YouTube of a presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftZ_DZHwWm4) I gave at a teacher's conference (explanation [starts here](https://youtu.be/ftZ_DZHwWm4?t=14m50s)).

Comment: Thanks Dominik. I was able to figure this out pretty easily. Your slides are helpful.